# Testcafe studio - how to process native dialogs

Tags: dialog, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I used testcafe studio to do my tests, but I had a problem. The problem shows "`Use the "setNativeDialogHandler" function to introduce a handler function for native dialogs.`", but I can't find it in testcafe studio.

Can help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

TestCafe Studio does not support recording actions for native dialogs. This capability will be added in one of the future releases.

Currently, you can only add the [setNativeDialogHandler](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/400174/test-actions/browser-actions#handle-native-dialogs) function manually.